# What are some of the key identifiers/characters of an undervalued stock?

Tags: stocks, value-investing, equity

How do you identify an undervalued stock? PE? EPS? Book Value?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. If there was a reliable way to identify an undervalued stock, then people would immediately buy it, its price would rise and it wouldn't be undervalued any more.

Comment: This is an overly simplistic answer. I would have expected to see at least some *best-effort* or examples of other approximate ways to do this. After all, this is done all day long by investors all over the globe, so...

Answer (score 0):

P/E = price per earnings. low P/E (P/E < 4) means stock is undervalued.
[image]

Comment: What about a negative P/E? Not sure the stock is undervalued in that case yet Mathematically, the P/E would be low.

Comment: What about Book value and Cash holding per share? Would that matter?

Comment: of course i meant P/E > 0. I am a noob myself, not an expert. But the more metrics you factor in, how do you combine all of them into a single number? So I preferred to give a simple answer.

Comment: also see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price%E2%80%93earnings_ratio) Either the stock is undervalued, or the company's earnings are thought to be in decline